# Is sex allowed during mononucleosis?

Tags: sex, disease, mononucleosis

I've been diagnosed with mono 3 weeks ago. I've talked to the doctor and he said that I should avoid any kind of physical activity because it may enlarge my spleen damage it seriously. Is it True? Is it forbidden for me to have sex? and if it is could you please tell me how long should I avoid it?